# svn check out from repository A and commit to repository B

Tags: svn, copy, commit

I checkout trunk from svn repository A and do the build on build server. After the build is successful, The results of the build (bin directory) I want to commit to repository B. I work on windows. How can I achieve this ? Below is the script I tried, but I got the error:

```
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: 'https://repositoryB' is not a local path
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: Commit targets must be local paths
svn: E205000: ''https://repositoryB'' is not a local path
```

Below is my script: (On build server with repository A checkout) and 
$destination = Repository B path

```
Copy-Item bin\Release\*.* -Destination $directory -Force
svn add $destination--force --depth infinity --username ADMIN
svn commit $destination--message $svnComment --depth infinity --username ADMIN --trust-server-cert --non-interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add or commit to a repository path. You need to give it a working-copy path. So you need to either set up a working copy to throw stuff into, or you need to `svn checkout` a new working copy in your script.

After you accomplish that, decide whether you really want to `svn add` *new* file locations every single time, or whether you want to replace an old file with a new version. If the latter, you need to remove the `svn add` command from your script. Otherwise, you'll need to either specify a NEW path every time, or `svn rm` and `svn commit` the old stuff every time before you copy the new stuff. Personally I think just committing modified files makes the most sense.

Comment: I could able to achieve what I was looking for without checking out using "svn import", it is combination of both 'svn add' + 'svn commit'.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to achieve what I was looking for without checking out the repository. I got it using "svn import", it is a combination of both 'svn add' + 'svn commit'. so, the code is : `svn import bin\Release\*.* $destination -m "commit msg"`

Using svn import... we can commit to the repository without doing svn check out.